# Marker search function in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working on a KnockoutJS App and trying to implement a marker search functionality. The idea is to perform a search on the search bar using the name and corresponding markers will be filtered with the listed display. The following function does the filtering -

```
my.myDataFilter = function(){

        my.FilteredList = ko.pureComputed(function() {
                if(my.query() === "") {
                  return my.points; 
                } 

                else {
                  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(my.points(), function(item) {
                      return item.name().toLowerCase().indexOf(my.query().toLowerCase())>-1;
                });
            }         
        }, this);

    }
```

Search bar is here in HTML -

```
<header> 
                <form action="#"> 
                    <input class="search" placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: my.query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off"> 
                </form> 
            </header>
```

and possible display -

```
<div class="con"> 
                <h3>Filtered List</h3>
                <ul data-bind="template: {name:'beer', foreach: my.FilteredList}"> 
                </ul> 
            </div>
```

my.loadMap function is below -

```
my.loadMap = function(item){ 
        my.pusMarkerData(item);

    }
```

The function pushes the marker data is -

```
my.query = ko.observable("");

    my.pusMarkerData = function(item){

        // console.log(item);
        my.points = ko.observableArray();  
        for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++){
            my.points.push( new my.mapMarker( item[j]['category'], item[j]['name'], item[j]['lat'], item[j]['lon']));
        } 
    }
```

My questions are -

1. How to call  my.loadMap(testValues) after I get my.FilteredList to show the filtered markers ?
2. The filter function using the search bar is not exactly what I'm trying to implement. Here is an example of what intend in jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mythical/XJEzc/

Thanks

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Single page map application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
        <header> 
            <form action="#"> 
                <input class="search" placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: my.query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off"> 
            </form> 
        </header> 

        <div class="content"> 
            <h3>Complete List</h3>
            <ul data-bind="template: {name:'beer', foreach:my.points}"> 
            </ul> 
        </div>

        <div class="con"> 
            <h3>Filtered List</h3>
            <ul data-bind="template: {name:'beer', foreach: my.FilteredList}"> 
            </ul> 
        </div> 

        <script type="text/html" id="beer"> 
            <li>
                <strong data-bind="text: category"></strong>
            </br>
                <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: lat"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: lon"></span>
            </li>
        </script> 

        <div id="map"></div> 
        <div id="eat" data-bind="template: { name: 'pointsTmpl', foreach: my.points }"></div>
        <script id="pointsTmpl" type="text/html">
            <p>
                <span data-bind="text: category"></span>; 
                <span data-bind="text: lat"></span>;
                <span data-bind="text: lon"></span>
            </p>
        </script>

        <!-- list of the imports  -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>                
        <script src="js/lib/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/data.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <!-- 
            <script src="js/lib/jQuery.js"></script>
            <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
            <script data-require="knockout@*" data-semver="3.3.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script> 
        -->

</body>
```

### app.js

```
$( function() {

my.createMap = function(){

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: my.sampleData.zoomLevel,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( my.sampleData.centerCoordinates[0], my.sampleData.centerCoordinates[1] ),

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions); // vanilla JS
    my.map = new google.maps.Map( $('#map')[0], myOptions); // using jQuery
}

my.mapMarker = function ( category, name, lat, lon) {

    this.category = ko.observable(category);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.lat = ko.observable(lat);
    this.lon = ko.observable(lon);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        title: name,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, 
        map: my.map,
        draggable: false
    });

    // draging for the markers 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        var pos = marker.getPosition();
        this.lat(pos.lat());
        this.lon(pos.lng());
    }.bind(this));

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        var pos = marker.getPosition();
        this.lat(pos.lat());
        this.lon(pos.lng());
    }.bind(this)); 
}

my.query = ko.observable("");

my.pusMarkerData = function(item){

    // console.log(item);
    my.points = ko.observableArray();  
    for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++){
        my.points.push( new my.mapMarker( item[j]['category'], item[j]['name'], item[j]['lat'], item[j]['lon']));
    } 
}

my.myDataFilter = function(){

    my.FilteredList = ko.pureComputed(function() {
            if(my.query() === "") {
              return my.points; 
            } 

            else {
              return ko.utils.arrayFilter(my.points(), function(item) {
                  return item.name().toLowerCase().indexOf(my.query().toLowerCase())>-1;
            });
        }         
    }, this);

}

my.loadMap = function(item){ 
    my.pusMarkerData(item);      
}

my.vm = function (){
    my.loadMap( my.sampleData.geoCoordinates ); 
} 

var test = new my.vm();

my.createMap();
ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
```

});

### data.js

```
var my = my || { }; //my namespace

my.dataservice = (function (my) {

    "use strict";
    var getDataSet = function () {
        return my.sampleData;
    };

    return {
        getData: getDataSet
    };
})(my);

my.sampleData = (function (my) {

    "use strict";

    var data = {

        geoCoordinates : [

            { 'category':'Movie', 'name': "A beautiful mind", 'lat':25.758199, 'lon':-80.373668},
            {'category':'Movie', "name":  "Fight club",'lat':25.756769, 'lon':-80.369463},
            {'category':'TV shows', "name": "House of cards",'lat':25.754064, 'lon':-80.373582} 
        ],
        centerCoordinates : [25.754296, -80.377531],
        zoomLevel : 16
    }

    return {
        geoCoordinates : data.geoCoordinates,
        centerCoordinates: data.centerCoordinates,
        zoomLevel: data.zoomLevel
    };

})(my);
```

Comment: What are you asking? Is something not working?

Comment: aquinas @ I would like to provide a search function using the name (my.sampleData.geoCoordinates.name) in the top right corner of the application. So, when you start writing the first few letters of the name on the search bar, the other options on the list will be filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is just a big wall of code. A LOT has to change. Take a look at this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/txUxPhvR9V8xi2pkcRli?p=preview

The basic thing you want to do is:

1) bind your list to a computed property: like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul data-bind="template: {name:'beer', foreach:my.FilteredList}">
    </ul>
</div>
```

2) Create the computed property as a filtered version of your complete list:

```
my.FilteredList = ko.computed(function() {
   if (my.query() === "") {
      return my.points;
   } 
   else {
     return ko.utils.arrayFilter(my.points(), function(item) {
        return item.name().toLowerCase().indexOf(my.query().toLowerCase()) > -1;
   });
};
```

3) Don't name your variables things like: "beer".